# laravel new project not running still loading in browser

Tags: php, laravel, browser, console, laravel-artisan

1. installing laravel new project

```sh
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel newProject
```

Project running perfect in `http://localhost:8000/` in this port 
after some time page loading stil

and clear everything in this project i think its cache error

```sh
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

project running for 2 min then still again loading

then this project change port like

`php artisan serve --port 9000`
same as working for 2 or 3 min then still loading

i dont know whats problem in this project any idea for this ?

`i tried same project on my second system working fine`

Comment: php artisan route:cache   try this command

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: window ( OS )  xampp server in locally

Comment: @Indian_ontop i got this error in my console command line ` Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.`

Comment: Show us the code inside your routes (web.php and api.php)

Comment: @Developer https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/why-unable-to-prepare-route-for-serialization-uses-closure this may help you

Comment: @pr1nc3 see my code

Comment: restart your xampp or laragon server...

Comment: @CoD_Arkalodia_3 already tryed restart xampp and aloso restart my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yah i got a answer

its not a php error operating system problem

thats why auto remove `server.php` file in my project

- Its better solution is update your operating system
- `php artisan serve` manually serve project its working fine like `php -S localhost:8000 -t path`

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/user', 'YourController@YourControllerFunction')->middleware('auth');
```

Or if you have many api's that need to use the authentication middleware then create a group like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/user', 'YourController@YourControllerFunction');
});
```

Also keep in mind that the auth:api middleware requires a token to be generated for user authentication.

Comment: i am using api why its error comming and my error is page still loading i dont know how any idea

Comment: Edited my answer can you try again?

Comment: hi bro i think you are not getting my point my auth is working fine 
i think error is cache problem. i tried my system restart but same still loading wihout login.

Comment: One more thing bro i tried same project on my second system working fine any idea for this

Comment: Are you using artisan serve command in your second system? Also in your env file do you have `APP_KEY` value ?

Comment: yes same as but working fine but same project first system got error refresh

Comment: and i have api key and regenrate for usng this command `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: What do you mean by error refresh? What is the error? Can you paste it? Enable the debugging and paste the error here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195454/discussion-between-developer-and-pr1nc3).